# kafka spark streaming cpu usage keep on increasing with time

Tags: apache-spark

I am streaming kafka topics with spark but when program starts it takes upto 10% of cpu usage, but after some hours it goes upto 150% cpu (2 cores).
my spark config:

```
val conf = new SparkConf(true)
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    .setAppName("Matix Processor")
    .set("spark.streaming.unpersist","true")
    .set("spark.cleaner.ttl","125")
```

and kafka stream :

```
val stream = KafkaUtils.createStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
    streamingContext, parameters, topics, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

plz somebody suggest what i am missing. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Your batch interval or data rate might be too short for processing each batch to finish before the next batch is ready. For example, if you have a 5 second batch window and it takes 5.1 seconds to process each batch, you'll slowly back up. So, you may need more cores or less data volume. You're using `local[*]`. Can you use a cluster instead?

Comment: got your point and my batch interval is of 1 second but couldn't understand how to use a cluster instead of local[*] ? first time i am using spark so plz help me to get out of this problem.

Comment: `local[*]` is for running on a single server. You may need a cluster of nodes to process your data, if a single server, even using all cores, can't keep up. See this page for more information: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html

Comment: Go to the spark ui and check the 'streaming' tab. Is your streaming `total time` < batch interval?